# Add key to authorized_users without needing to restart sshd

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to add a public key to a server but I don't want to restart the sshd service for it to take effect. The reason is that restarting the ssh service seems to be disruptive for other users who could use the ssh service at that time. Most documentation suggest to add a public key to `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` and then to restart the `sshd` service (`systemctl restart sshd`).

My questions are:

1. Is the restart of `sshd` needed?
2. If `sshd` is restarted, is there a service outage at that time?
3. Is there a way to set up passwordless auth using ssh without needing to restart the `sshd` service after adding new public keys to `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`?

Comment: This might get a better response on the [Unix SO](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Chase thanks. I'll keep this open for a bit of time and then close it.

Comment: No "bit of a time". Close it now! Your question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, the ssh daemon will automatically use the updated authorized_keys
2. Probably; in general you'd want to use "reload", not "restart", if you change configurations (though you don't need to do that for this)
3. Not a problem. (An easy way to copy the keys you're using into authorized_keys is with "ssh-copy-id", by the way.)